# How to improve the performance of UINavigationController's snapshot

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, uikit, snapshot

I use this block of code to take a snapshot of UINavigationController's view:

```
@implementation UIView (Snapshot)
- (UIImage*)snapshot
{
    NSTimeInterval t0 = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] systemUptime];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.frame.size, self.opaque, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
    if([self isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]){
        CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, -((UIScrollView*)self).contentOffset.y);
    }
    [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *snapshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    NSTimeInterval t1 = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] systemUptime];
    NSLog(@"time cost: %lf", t1 - t0);
    return snapshotImage;
}
@end
```

1,

```
JASidePanelController *sidePanelController = //...
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:sidePanelController];
[navController.view snapshot]; // **cost 1 seconds**
```

2,

```
JASidePanelController *sidePanelController = //...
UINavigationController *navController = //...;
sidePanelController.centerPanel = navController;
[navController.view snapshot]; // **cost 0.1 seconds**
```

Any methods to improve the performance?

I found the reason:
it is because JASideController add UIBezierPath to view.layer in 
(void)styleContainer:(UIView *)container animate:(BOOL)animate duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration

Comment: When I tried this, I got around 0.002 seconds for self.view and self.navigationController.view, so I'm not seeing this difference.

Comment: @rdelmar, sorry I forgot to give the device type. I tested it on iPod Touch 4. Human could feel the operation is slow on iPhone 4S too. While on iPhone 5, the speed is very fast.

Comment: I get 0.028 for self.view and 0.034 for self.navigationController.view on an iPhone 4. I'd be surprised that it would be slower on a 4S. I don't know why yours would be so much slower.

Comment: My navigation controller's rootViewController is an instance of JASidePanelController(https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels), it contains three childViewControllers. Each child view controller contains a table view with a list of image and text items.
It is very slow to call [naviationController.view snapshot] here.
After entering the next level(a detail view controller which displays a piece of news), [naviationController.view snapshot] turns  to be very fast, less than 0.1 on iPod Touch 4.

Comment: @rdelmar, thanks for your comments. The problem is very weird. Just started a new project, created a UINavigationController with JASidePanelController as rootViewController, set three very simple childViewControllers. It cost 0.1 seconds on iPod touch 4. It seems no direct relation with UINavigationController and JASidePanelController. 
I decide to check my code again.

Comment: I found the reason why it is slow, have no idea how to resolve it yet.
I have updated the question.

Comment: May I suggest a compromise? Why not take the snapshot in the background? This is one of the only things possible to perform in a background thread that are related to UI.